# No internet IPv6 connectivity in lan or wireless on windows 11

Tags: windows, ipv6

Me PC recently crashed afterwards my onboard Bluetooth completely vanished Windows couldn't find any trace of it even tho the WiFi on the same card was fine ended up spending hours deleting and reinstalling stuff with no joy so I switched it off went to sleep woke up and went at it again took a quick gaming break then tried again and I got it working but now have no Internet on my IPv6 connectivity have tried everything but no joy am about to use my PC as a trampoline? Can any 1 help

Comment: Please format your post to make it more readable than one long sentence.

Comment: Uninstall the Wireless card driver, restart, then install the newest version of Wireless card driver. This completely resets the driver parameters.

Comment: If nothing works for you, the crash probably killed your Bluetooth adapter. Perhaps a power surge fried it (and maybe other stuff too).

Answer (score 0):

1. There was probably no ipv6 connectivity on your PC to begin with. You must have never noticed that before. Whenever you'r ISP only provide ipv4 connectivity, "no Internet on my IPv6 connectivity" is a intended behavior.
2. Your computer crashing and Bluetooth diasppearing is a completely unrelated hardware issue. You may want to replace wireless card if you really need Bluetooth on that PC.